# verifier of addition... not-regular, but is it context-free?

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language

How can I show that the following language is (not) context-free? The argument that it's not regular goes as follows.

[image]

I suspect this language to be context-free... The reason why I think this, is because L = {a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>m</sup> c<sup>{n+m}</sup> | n,m >= 0} is context-free. A proof for this can be found at

http://cg.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/TheoryOfComputation/TheoryOfComputation.pdf (p102 in pdf; p94 in text)

The proof is kind of long and it can probably be proven much shorter by making use of the equivalence with PDAs (i.e. pushing first some symbol n "+" m times on the stack, and consequently taking it off again n+m times.) Either way, this example makes me believe that my original language must also be context-free. Yet, I don't really see how I can argue for this.

Comment: I think this SE site is better for this kind of questions: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, your assumption is not correct!

The language `L = { x = y + z | where x, y, z are binary integers and x is the sum of y and z}` is *not* Context Free Languages(CFL).

I try to explain.

First of all, consider following examples strings `s` in language `L`.

```
110 = 100 + 10   
1110 = 1100 + 10  
:
111000 = 110000 + 1000
```

In my explanation LHS is `X` in question and RHS is  `Y + Z`.

[**What is pumping Lemma for CFL?**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages)
If a language L is context-free, then there exists some integer p ≥ 1 such that any string s in L with |s| ≥ p. (where p is a "pumping length"  can be written as

```
s = uvxyz
with substrings u, v, x, y and z, such that
1. |vxy| ≤ p,
2. |vy| ≥ 1, and
3. uv nxy nz is in L for every natural number n.
```

This definition | ≥ 1, and
    3. uv nxy nz is in L for every natural number n.

**Notice:** Middle part of `s` , `vxy` not greater then pumping length `p`. (condition 1)

**[SOLUTION]**:

Let us choose a string `s` in `L` that satisfy condition  `|s| ≥ p`

our  `s` is  1<sup>m</sup>0<sup>q</sup> = 1<sup>m-1</sup>0<sup>q</sup>  + 10<sup>q</sup>   ,  where  `q > p , m-1 > p`

Now total length of `s` is  `2m + 2q -1` that is greater then `p` and of-course for some combination of natural numbers this inequality is possible (I am not including length of `+` and `=` to keep explanation simple )

Now our `s` is in language and sufficiently large according to pumping lemma for CFG.

Now break it:

u **vxy** z = 1<sup>m</sup>0<sup>q</sup> = 1<sup>m-1</sup>0<sup>q</sup>  + 10<sup>q</sup>

Try to find `v` and `y` to pump and generate new string in language L, But keep in mind `v` and `y` should not be too much far than `p` (according to condition 1).

You don't have any choice for `v`  and `y` such that you can generate new strings in language!

**(Step-1):** Because if you chose to increase `1` then you can't pump both side RHS and LHS of `=` because last `1` on LHS is at `q` (>p) to first `1` of RHS. hence not possible to generate new strings in language.

**(Step-2):** Suppose you like to pump `0` again its not possible to increase `0` on LHS and RHS together because last `0` on LHS in m-1 (>p) distend to first `0` on RHS.

**(Step-3):** You can't pump a combination of `111...000...`  both side. , try this you will get string out of language L.

Try other options too within the rules of Pumping Lemma. you would not find correct choice for `v` and `y`.

**[ANSWER]**

So he have a string `s` in L that is sufficiently large and using that we can't generate new strings in language. its contradict to Pumping Lemma for CFL hence given `L` is not a CFL.

Comment: `1^m0^q = 1^m-10^q + 10^q` - Is this a mistake? It seems wrong. E.g. if m=3, q=1 you get `1110 = 110 + 10` which isn't true, the correct sum would be `1000 = 110 + 10`

Comment: It should be `1^m0^q = 1^(m-1)0^(q+1) + 10^q`